# How to Select one row in a table for every row in another table using linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

My question is confusing, so i try my best to explain the problem, assume i have two tables, Product and ProductPictures:
[image]

So according to model every product may have one or more pictures, i want select a product which it's `Id` is equal to `productId` and it has `ProductPicturePath` too, in other word i want to select `Product.ProductName, ProductPictures.ProductPicturePath, Product.ProductDescription, Product.Price`

So i try this:

```
  [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetProducstDetail(int productId)
    {

        var resultProduct = from product in db.Products
                            from productPicture in (from firstProductPicture in db.ProductPictures where firstProductPicture.ProductId==product.Id select firstProductPicture.ProductPicturePath).FirstOrDefault()
                            where product.Id == productId
                            select new { product.ProductName, productPicture, product.ProductDescription, product.Price };


        if (resultProduct == null)
        {
            return Json(-1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
       return Json(resultProduct, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

but it gives me error : `DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType. Parameter name: input` , how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `ProductPictures` navigational property:

```
var resultProduct = 
    from product in db.Products
    where product.Id == productId && product.ProductPictures.Any()
    select new 
    { 
        product.ProductName,
        product.ProductPictures.FirstOrDefault().ProductPicturePath,
        product.ProductDescription, 
        product.Price 
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query has no `equals clause` .

Try this

```
var resultProduct = db.Products.Where(i => i.Id == productId).Select(t => new
                {
                    ProductName = t.ProductName, 
                    productPicture = ( db.ProductPictures
                                       .Where( i=> i.ProductId == t.Id)             
                                        Select(i => i.ProductPicturePath)
                                       .FirstOrDefault()
                                      ), 
                    ProductDescription = t.ProductDescription, 
                    Price = t.Price 
                });
```

Comment: thank u, it work for me +1 for that, but i want a linq solution